# Identify Influential predictors

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-models, feature-selection, predictor, importance

I have a dataset with binary class as outcome. I was exploring the data through plotting the variables for both the classes.

For example, something like below

```
df_dummies.groupby('OP_flag').Age.plot(kind='kde')
```

produces a graph like as shown below

[image]

How do I know that the difference in distribution that we see between the classes is significant enough?

So that I can know that this is an important variable in predicting the output or not.

Please note that this is done during data exploration.